# Creating an Image that is completely transparent

Tags: java, image

I want to create an Image object which is absolutely transparent. The JFrame method

```
createImage(int x, int y);
```

is totally useless, because it creates a white rectangle, not a transparent one. In the past, I loaded in a PNG file that was transparent, but there must be a simpler way to do it.

Comment: well please and your question is ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)? It is a base class for working with images in standard java. It supports ARGB image types that includes alpha channel (transparency) along with standard RGB.
You can try something like this to create transparent image:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics gr = image.getGraphics();
gr.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)); // last component is alpha channel. 
                                    // 0 - transparent, 255 - opaque
gr.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100):
// Now image is transparent
```

I didn't test it but it should work.